# Using confidence level for locateOnScreen pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

I want to use confidence level in my klocateOnScreen function of pyautogui module. For that to work I need to install opencv package, I installed it form a wheel file as the conda install opencv-python was not working in my case. I can see the package installed. But, I still cannot use the confidence parameter. Please help.

username = py.locateOnScreen("username.png", region=(0,0, 824, 616), grayscale=True, confidence=0.95)

Comment: did you try smaller value - ie `confidence=0.7` or `confidence=0.5` ? Maybe you simply need different value because image is too different. OR maybe you should crop image to remove some diffferences. OR maybe you search in wrong region - did you try without `region`?

Answer (score 0):

grayscale is good, because the programm can detect the image faster, but if it makes problems i wouldn't use it.
Also as furas said the confidence is pretty high, you can lower it if there are no similar images in that region. I don't know what u want to do exactly, but maybe you can hide the "username.png" on the screen somehow and check if there is nothing else detected as that image with lower confidence.

```
import pyautogui as pg
import time
import random

while 1:
if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('username.png', region=(0,0,824,616),confidence=0.85) != None:
    print("I can see username")
    time.sleep(.5)
```

If the programm can see the username.png, even it is hidden your confidence is to low.